# Non-trivial solution to certain elliptic PDE implies exponential growth.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

In a paper I am reading there is a line which I don't quite understand. The setup is the following. We have a compact Riemannian manifold $N$, then we consider the cylinder $M=\mathbb{R} \times N$ and we have a *nontrivial* solution $u:M\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ of the problem

$(D_t^2+\Delta_N)u-Ku=0$

where $\Delta_N$ is the Laplace-Beltrami operator on the cross section $N$ and $K>0$ is a constant. It then says "since the solution is non-trivial, it must exhibit exponential growth in either the $t\rightarrow \infty$ or $t\rightarrow -\infty$ directions.

Could somebody explain why this is necessarily true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is $D_{t}^{2} = \partial_{tt}$? Is the PDE some sort of wave equation on an infinite cylinder? And are you sure it is $\color{red}+ \Delta_{N}$ not $\color{red}- \Delta_{N}$?

Comment: Yes, it is, and yes I'm sure. The part $D^2_t+\Delta_N$ is in fact the Laplace-Beltrami on the product manifold with metric $dt^2+g$ where $g$ is the metric on $N$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your sign convention is such that $\Delta_N$ has positive spectrum (e.g. $\Delta_{\mathbb R} = -\partial_x^2$), giving a wave-like equation, this is not necessarily true: the bounded solution $u = \sin(2 x)\sin(t)$ of $(\partial_t^2-\partial_x^2)u-3u=0$ on $\mathbb R/2 \pi \mathbb Z$ is a counterexample.

Thus I'll assume you use the opposite convention. Some well-known functional analysis tells us that there's an orthonormal basis of $\Delta_N$-eigenfunctions $e_i$ (for some sensible Hilbert space - I think this is true for $\mathcal D(\Delta)\subset L^2$ from memory?) with corresponding negative eigenvalues $\lambda_i;$ so writing $u(x,t)=\sum_i u_i(t) e_i(x)$ the PDE becomes $$u_i''(t)+(\lambda_i-K)u_i(t)=0.$$

Since the coefficient $-k^2 := \lambda_i - K$ of $u_i(t)$ is negative, the general solution is $u_i(t) = c_1 e^{kt} + c_2 e^{-kt},$ which must grow exponentially in a direction unless it vanishes identically. Thus, if $u$ is non-trivial, one of its projections $u_i$ must grow exponentially, and since $\|u(\cdot,t)\|^2=\sum_i|u_i(t)|^2$ we conclude that $u(t)$ must grow exponentially, at least in the $L^2$ norm. I think you should be able to get exponential growth of $\sup|u|$ without too much extra effort.

Comment: Does the same argument hold if we replace $K$ by some smooth non-negative function $F(x)$ which is independent of $t$? (it obviously should, but I'd like to ask you if you don't mind) In that case the spectrum of $\Delta_N-F(x)$ is non-positive (so we won't necessarily get exponential growth, but at least linear).

Comment: @TheManWhoNeverSleeps: It's harder to see how an eigendecomposition approach would work there - I think a non-constant $F$ would introduce mixing/coupling. Could try something more in the spirit of a maximum principle argument.

Comment: But if we consider the operator $L=\Delta_N - F(x)$ with $x$ being a coordinate on $N$, the eigenvalues would satisfy $\lambda \leq 0$, so if we used the eigen-decomposition we would obtain $u_i''=-\lambda_i u_i$.

Comment: Oh, you're right of course. If $N$ is compact I think you should get a spectral gap $ \cdots < \lambda_2 \le \lambda_1 < 0$ and thus still achieve exponential growth like $e^{\lambda_1 t}$, no? Or am I off track? I'm super rusty.

Comment: No worries, I'm rusty too, which is why I'm asking. It looks like this is true as long as $F(x)$>0 at some point in $N$, and then indeed we should get a spectral gap. If $F(x)=0$ Then we can have constant functions with eigenvalue $0$.